# Form validation in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Scenario is that  one user has many devices and i want to make sure device name must be unique.like user Barry has device with name device_1 and when he adds new device the device name must be unique but second user wally has device with name device_1 so how would implement ? Code is given below

```
public function rules()
    {
        $user_id=(double)Input::get('user_id');

        return [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'device_name' => 'required|unique:devices,device_name,'.$user_id.',user_id',
            'sensorPin_num' => 'required|integer',
            'relay_num'  =>'required|integer'

            //
        ];
    }
```

Comment: This code check all records in device table but i want  to check according to given user id.

Answer (score 0):

You should add device's id if your updating or null if you're creating first, for example if the above code is from the model:

```
$device_id = $this->id ?: null;
```

Here is the write unique rule:

```
'device_name' => 'required|unique:devices,device_name, '. $device_id .',id,user_id,'.$user_id;
```

Comment: Why we need device's id??